# Get nodes with the same term a node

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to make a block, with views, that shows me a list of nodes that has the same term of the node that I'm viewing:

- I open node/1 that has a term reference field to the term "10"
- I want to display other nodes that have a reference to the same term

I use a contextual filter, but how should I pass the term?
Have I to use a php value as default argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, it is really easy with powerful Views module.
There is cool option for contextual filters “Content: Has taxonomy term ID” and “Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)” — *Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks*.
[image]

**Tip:** don't forget to exclude node, which is current!
[image]

Comment: Good, I didn't know this function!! :)