# How to show users with the same term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I added a term reference field (field_department_term_ref) to user entity (/admin/config/people/accounts/fields), then I need use Views to list all the users with the same term as current logged in user (including current logged in user himself). I referenced [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49899/get-nodes-with-the-same-term-a-node), But unfortunately there are 2 differences:

1. Contextual filter "User: field_department_term_ref" can not get the right default value.
2. If I don't select the "Exclude" checkbox in the MORE section, it will only show current user himself; if not, it will show others users but no current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it provides a way to pass the term from current node and not from user. But there are two different ways to do this :

1. By Custom Code : Get the term id using `$user` variable and pass term id to the [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) function which is used to render the views.
2. Create two views :

   - **First view** : User list with contextual filter `term` field that is added in account settings.
   - **Second View** : User view with contextual filter `uid` that filters the
     current logged in user.

     -- In field section add `term id` field and
     `exclude` it from there.

     -- Next field would be the first view  which
     prints the list of users by taking the term argument.

     -- Pass the token
     of `tid` in argument section of view field.

To add a views as a field you need a module : [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view).

Comment: I used your second method, it works nicely! Thank you!